# How to get output to show up in cmd window during Ruby script running (Windows 7)

Tags: ruby, watir

ruby 1.9.2
watir 1.8.1

We start our ruby script from the cmd prompt (driver.rb).
The ruby script then performs the following line to execute a cmd prompt command:

```
response = `choice /c 12 /n /m "1. Qual -- 2. Test"`
```

I would like the prompt window to display the choice to allow the user to make the selection and then return the selection.

When the command is executed, the message is not displayed but the cmd window is waiting for a response.

When I enter the value (1 or 2), it returns the string

```
(/c 12 /n /m "1. Qual -- 2. Test x)
```

with x being the value I chose.

When the ruby script is done executing, then I see the prompt in the cmd window.

When we run, any output from the ruby script (e.g. puts) shows up after the script has ended.

Is there a way to have the output go to the cmd window while ruby is running and not wait until is has ended or at least have the cmd prompt command show up?

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: I don't have this issue. I put `(0..5).each { |i| puts i; sleep 1 }` in a ruby file and I ran it in `cmd` in Windows 7, and I got an output each second, not all at once in the end of running.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to execute choice? You could perfectly do with pure-ruby using gets and even better using Highline gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/highline

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to help you if you talked about what question you have that you thought 'choice' was the answer to. Why do you want somebody to choose Qual or Test after the test has started running? There are ways to pass in parameters to ruby, or about a million other ways to have options without asking a question at a dos prompt.

Comment: I don't see any Watir in the above code, why does this have a Watir tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are requiring or including other ruby scripts, the code in those scripts gets executed.  That's not a problem if all they do is define classes, methods, etc.  However if there is actual code in those files which is not part of defining an object or method, it'd going to execute, ahead of any other flow control etc in your main script.

I can't say for sure if that's what is happening to you, but it sounds like it might be the case depending on how you are trying to structure things.